# Convert homomorphically encrypted decimal number to homomorphically encrypted binary number

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

I am trying to convert a homomorphically encrypted integer to a homomorphically encrypted binary number (in vector form like {Ciphertext(1),Ciphertext(1),Ciphertext(0),Ciphertext(1)}), which I cannot really get the remainder (and any other "intermediate results") without decryption.

Is there really a way to do this?

Comment: That may depend on the FHE scheme that you are using. Generally, that is too way hard to do. Better way is to use binary in the beginning!

Comment: FHE is by definition Turing Complete HE, so it's certainly possible there. But not all HE is FHE.

Comment: Which homomorphic scheme are using? How are you encrypting the messages? Simply one message per ciphertext or using some batching technique to encrypt several messages into one ciphertext?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question could be change to "How to evaluate mod $N$ under FHE". For CKKS scheme, there exist approximations for that: https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/153.pdf